# React.JS: Using React reduxjs-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to use "@reduxjs/toolkit"

So I have a page: **"services.reducer.ts"**:

```
const initialState = {
  entities: [] as ReadonlyArray<IServices>,
  entity: defaultValue,
  loading: false,
  totalItems: 0
}
export type ServiceState = Readonly<typeof initialState>;


export const getEntities = createAsyncThunk(
  'services/getEntities',
  async () => {
    const response = await axios.get<any>(apiUrl)
    return response.data
  }
)

export const getEntity = createAsyncThunk(
  'services/getEntity',
  async (id: number | string) => {
    const response = await axios.get<any>(`${apiUrl}/${id}`);
    return response.data
  }
)

export const ServiceSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'services',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(getEntities.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
      })
      .addCase(getEntities.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { data } = action.payload;
        state.entities = data;
        state.loading = true;
        state.totalItems = parseInt(action.payload.length, 10);
      })
      .addCase(getEntity.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { data } = action.payload;
        state.entity = data;
      })
  }
})
```

on my services.tsx:

```
export const Services = (props: IServicesProps) => {
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
dispatch(getEntities())
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("resp ", resp)
        if (resp.payload !== null) {
          setLista(resp.payload)
        }
      })
}, []);
```

Now my question is: I would to use the info about loading and totalItems for example. But I don't understand how can I use in on my services.tsx

I have, for example, set:

```
        state.loading = true;
        state.totalItems = parseInt(action.payload.length, 10);
```

but I don't understand if they are declared in the right place or not.

EDIT:

store.ts

```
import { AnyAction, configureStore, ThunkAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import reducer from 'app/shared/reducers';
import errorMiddleware from './error-middleware';
import notificationMiddleware from './notification-middleware';
import loggerMiddleware from './logger-middleware';
import { loadingBarMiddleware } from 'react-redux-loading-bar';


const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }).concat(errorMiddleware, notificationMiddleware, loadingBarMiddleware(), loggerMiddleware),
})

const getStore = () => store;

export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<IRootState> = useSelector;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, IRootState, unknown, AnyAction>;

export default getStore;
```

EDIT 2:

```
import { loadingBarReducer as loadingBar } from 'react-redux-loading-bar';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authentication, { AuthenticationState } from './authentication';
import applicationProfile, { ApplicationProfileState } from './application-profile';

import administration, { AdministrationState } from 'app/modules/administration/administration.reducer';
import userManagement, { UserManagementState } from './user-management';
// prettier-ignore
import services, {
  ServiceState
} from 'app/entities/service/service.reducer';
// prettier-ignore

/* jhipster-needle-add-reducer-import - JHipster will add reducer here */

export interface IRootState {
  readonly authentication: AuthenticationState;
  readonly applicationProfile: ApplicationProfileState;
  readonly administration: AdministrationState;
  readonly userManagement: UserManagementState;
  readonly services: ServicesState;
  readonly loadingBar: any;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers<IRootState>({
  authentication,
  applicationProfile,
  administration,
  userManagement,
  services,
  ,
  /* jhipster-needle-add-reducer-combine - JHipster will add reducer here */
  loadingBar,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

EDIT 3: console.log("resp", resp):

```
{
    "type": "services/getEntities/fulfilled",
    "payload": [
        {
            "srvCod": 1,
            "srvDescod": "Account Savings",
            "srvDescodmaia": "Corporate Islan",
            "srvDestitle": "Oklahoma",
        },
        
    ],
    "meta": {
        "arg": {
            "sortParam": "srvCod,asc",
            "pageParam": 0
        },
        "requestId": "OTD4JuHBUeYF7ueyg6BQ2",
        "requestStatus": "fulfilled"
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to first import your service reducer into store.js, so that it can available throughout the app and then useSelector hook inside services.tsx file to grab loading value

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal thank you for your answer! So I have to import it in my store, but where ?

Comment: It has to be part of the `reducers` object that you import from `app/share/reducers`. You don't show that code.

Comment: @phry thank you for answer :) I have imported yet it in my app/share/reducers ( edit2 code)

Comment: Ok I have tried to console.log useSelector((state) => state) and I can see loading and totalItems, but entities and entity results undefined, do you know why?

Comment: @Jack23 can you show console.log("resp",resp) value?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal I have edited the post :)